# Ocaml - Constructor with a polymorphic argument

Tags: types, polymorphism, ocaml

In an interpreter for a toy functional language, I have an `expr` type which has one constructor for each arithmetic and boolean operator. I'd like to factorize this type into something like:

```
type expr =
    | Int of int
    | BinaryArith of (int -> int -> int) * expr * expr
    | Comparison of ('a -> 'a -> bool)   * expr * expr
```

However this will not type as the `'a` type parameter is undefined. I could fully parametrize as `'a expr`, but a single instance of `expr` would no longer offer a polymorphic behaviour.

Ultimately, my wish is to pass the built-in comparison operators (`<>`, `>=`, etc) to the constructor, so I'd like to preserve full polymorphism here.

A simple reason that would make it impossible, if constructors can be viewed as functions, is that the Hindley-Milner type system only supports "prenex" polymorphism.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is there a proper way of achieving this kind of polymorphism?

Edit: Although the accepter answer addresses the question, better designs were suggested in the other answers and the comments. Make sure to read them!

Comment: You might want to learn about GADT to achieve something like this.

Comment: Note that since functions are opaque values you will not be able to implement any useful operations on `expr`s. They will not even print usefully in the toplevel. Étienne's approach is the way to go.

Comment: @RichouHunter : Thank you for the advice! This notion is still pretty advanced for my level of study but it feels really appropriate. I will definitely have a closer look at it.

Comment: @gsg : Yes, I realized later that I could not pattern-match a function and expect it to work like a function pointer comparison in C. Given the state of my implementation right now, Étienne's technique is definitely better.

Comment: @lephe: It's never too soon to start learining, GADT are a wide topic indeed.

Comment: @RichouHunter : After trying an implementation, I can tell it's really expressive. Wow! Unfortunately the language needs some form of polymorphism, and I'm afraid I won't be able to pull that off on time (given some problems that I am currently facing). I'll make sure to come back to them when I have the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't rule out that this is an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), but in case you really need that, it is possible since OCaml 4.03 to have [inline records](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec271), i.e. to declare records type (that can have fully polymorphic fields) directly as parameters of type constructors, as in:

```
type expr =
  | Int of int
  | BinaryArith of (int -> int -> int)
  | Comparison of { compare: 'a. 'a -> 'a -> bool }

let e = Comparison { compare = Pervasives.(=) }
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning records. As for the XY issue: having a constructor for each operator seems bad design to me (especially since they are functions). I'm really just trying to improve my implementation, and I hope my question reflects that.

Answer (score 4):

It's not exactly answering your question, but you might want to keep your AST more symbolic. For example:

```
type comparison_op = Eq | Ne | Lt | Gt | Le | Ge

type expr = ... | Comparison of comparison_op * expr * expr
```

And then, when you are evaluating expressions, you can call `(=)` or `(<=)` etc.